# javascript property deletion

Tags: javascript

Just wondering about this one :

Whats the difference, or is there a difference at all, between :

```
delete obj.someProperty
```

and

```
obj.someProperty=undefined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second version sets the property to the existing value `undefined` while the first removes the key from the object. The difference can be seen when iterating over the object or using the `in` keyword.

```
var obj = {prop: 1};
'prop' in obj; // true
obj.prop = undefined;
'prop' in obj; // true, it's there with the value of undefined
delete obj.prop;
'prop' in obj; // false
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference will be realized when iterating over the object. When deleting the property, it will not be included in the loop, whereas just changing the value to undefined will include it. The length of the object or number of iterations will be different.

Here is some great (albeit advanced) information on deleting in JavaScript:

http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: Thanks for the link, this is something that I've completely underestimated :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `delete` will actually remove the key itself from the object. If you set the value to `undefined`, they key still exists, but the value is the only thing that has changed.

Answer (score 2):

The former will actually delete the property, the latter will leave it but set it to `undefined`.

This becomes significant if you loop over all the properties (`for (props in obj) { }`) or test for the existence of one (`if ('someProperty' in obj) {}`)